# Is there a Jekyll UI to where we can input Blog posts without doing it by code?

Tags: jekyll

Is there a Jekyll UI to where we can input Blog posts without doing it by code?
Like in Wordpress where a non programmer can input blog posts.

Is there a module for this or a plugin?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: You can have a look at [this list from thenewdynamic.org](https://www.thenewdynamic.org/tools/content-management/).

Try [prose.io](http://prose.io/), [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) or [Cloudcannon](http://cloudcannon.com/) they both offer some UI to work with Jekyll.